# PostgreSql doesn't understand column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created table in PostgreSql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS es_events;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS es_events (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  version INT NOT NULL,
  data BYTEA NOT NULL
);
```

now i'm trying to select from this table:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(version),0)
                            FROM public.es_events
                            WHERE name = 'asd';
```

but as a result i receive:

```
ERROR:  column "version" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COALESCE(MAX(version),0)
                            ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "es_events.  version".
SQL state: 42703
Character: 21
```

i tried to use "es_events.  version" but it doesn'r help:

```
ERROR:  column "es_events.  version" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COALESCE(MAX("es_events.  version"),0)
                            ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 21
```

What i'm doing wrong? How to select from table ?

```
# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1)
```

Comment: This `"es_events.  version"` seems to indicate there are hidden space characters in the name. Try your select with `SELECT COALESCE(MAX("es_events.  version"),0) `or `SELECT COALESCE(MAX("  version"),0)` to confirm`.

Comment: @eshirvana, no the error is just showing the line the error occurred on. It does not  include the rest of the query as it is not relevant.

Comment: I tried to use "es_events.  version" insted of just "version", the same result - ERROR:  column "es_events.  version" does not exist

Comment: There are multiple spaces in the name. Cut and paste the column name as returned by the error. Also add to your question the output of `\dt es_events` in psql.

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message, you created the table with a column named `"  version"` (with two leading spaces) rather than `version`.

You can rename the column:

```
ALTER TABLE es_events RENAME "  version" to version;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I've recreated table with "REATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS es_events (id SERIAL,name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,version INT NOT NULL,data BYTEA NOT NULL)" it helped.

But why it was created with spaces previously? how to escape column names ? // i created table with help of pgAdmin

Comment: @MaximKitsenko. Use `psql`, pgAdmin is just an unnecessary layer that gets in the way more then it helps.

Comment: Column names are escaped using "these quotes"

Comment: I cannot say what you did to create this column. Perhaps entered a value with two leading spaces in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

There were spaces in `create table`, after fixing table creation script names started to work corectly:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS es_events (id SERIAL,name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,version INT NOT NULL,data BYTEA NOT NULL)
```